# Is there a way to write applications that firefox can use as default applications for certain file types in automator?

Tags: automator, firefox

I have been able to specify a simple automator application as a default application for a few URL types in firefox. For files, it correctly has the behavior of calling the script with the file path. But for protocol URLs that aren't downloaded and are instead passed along to the script, the script receives no data.

The simple automator app, run shell script, pass input as arguments:

```
<path>/open-handler "$@"
```

I also tried printing everything out explicitly:

```
echo "$@" > ~/tmp.log
echo > ~/tmp.log
cat > ~/tmp.log
<path>/open-handler "$@"
```

And tried passing input to stdin instead of args, but regardless of what I try, the script prints nothing (except empty lines, which are printed by line 2 above).

I did find [How to access a clicked URL in a URL handler application created in Automator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46666/how-to-access-a-clicked-url-in-a-url-handler-application-created-in-automator), though I'm not sure it's exactly what I'm looking for. In my case, firefox already knows which application to open, it's not an arbitrary url click, it's just not able to provide it the args it needs.

Alternatively, is there a way to get firefox to directly open an executable instead of app? Or alternatively, is there a way to package an executable in an app?

Comment: Are you just making some content type settings in Firefox, or are you declaring the URL protocol(s) for your app?

Comment: I am just making content type settings in Firefox. Is there a global URL protocol setting on macOS that I have to configure somehow?

Comment: If you are talking about responding to links in webpages, you would need to add the CFBundleURLTypes as mentioned in your linked topic, but a regular app will be needed as Automator isn’t set up to handle those events.